# MSBuild add file to primary output

Tags: file, msbuild, tfsbuild

How can i add some custom file created by MSBuild to project output? 
i.e. I have blank .csproj, I add Exec task to Target that generates some file.txt and now i want to include this file into "primary output" or "content files".

Thanks, 
Marek

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you just need to include the output files you have and then copy them to the output directory.

```
<CreateItem Include="$(SourcePath)\file.txt">
  <Output ItemName="FilesToCopy" TaskParameter="Include" />
</CreateItem>

<Copy SourceFiles="@(FilesToCopy)" DestinationFolder="$(OutDir)" />
```

There's also a variable $(OutputDirectory) for the immediate project.  There are many other properties you may find useful also:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164309.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164313.aspx